# APIGility - Multi DB at run time

Tags: laminas-api-tools

I am writing API for my application which has one fix database information, where based on user we decide the second database at run time.

How I can implement this in APIGility.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure this is an Apigility question? What kind of connection to you plan on using? In any case, if you configure your Apigility as code connected, you have 100% control of this, as Apigility only stubs your controllers, and you provide the services.

Comment: As @dualmon says you have 100% control. You should be able to get your resources from different databases by simply using different database adapters or object managers inside your listeners and/or controllers. What did you try and what does not work?